# how to get access to the field of already launched application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

inside controller there is a TextArea

the application to check if it is already running just exits without letting another instance start

```
    public class Main extends Application {

    private static Controller controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    AnchorPane anchorPane = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (Application Launch)) {
       //how to access the open application


       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader  = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
       controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
       controller.doSomeThing("myText");

        System.exit(0);
    }else {
        launch(args);
    }
```

that is a controller

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller {
@FXML
private TextArea textArea;

public void doSomeThing(String myText) {
    textArea.setText(myText);
}
}
```

Comment: You need the `Controller` from the `FXMLLoader`

Comment: @Raw  may be code show how to implement it?

Comment: Post your `Controller` ,than a can help you

Comment: So i have done an example just rename `MyController` to `Controller`

Comment: Then declare `private static Controller` and then use it in the main

Comment: See edit answer

Comment: Just show me your edit class where you done that what i have wrote in the answer

Comment: You should just add this Line `controller = fxmlLoader.getController();` under  `AnchorPane anchorPane = fxmlLoader.load..` and in the main methode only call `controller.doSomeThing("myText")`

Comment: I think you need to reword your question. You are trying to determine if an instance of your **application** is already running before allowing another one to start? Because you seem to be asking at least two questions. You also seem to want one application to access the `TextField` of another?

Comment: And instead of posting a very lengthy back-and-forth conversation, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (actually read that link, please). That is the best way for us to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If it was clear, you'd have an answer and the question wouldn't be closed. Drop the attitude, read the rules and guidelines here, and try again.

Comment: Believe what you want. You didn't get an answer, the question is closed, and I've explained why. Good luck getting help.

Comment: @Raw Thanks, the answer came in handy in another code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So a small example for you:

```
private static Controller controller;


FXMLLoader fxmlLoader  = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Parent anchorPane = fxmlLoader.load();

controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
controller.doSomeThing("myText");
...
```

And in the `Controller` define a `public` function.

MyController :

```
public void doSomeThing(String myText) {
    myTextField.setText(myText);
}
```

Comment: He has since edited the original post and removed this question. I think this answer could now be deleted.

Comment: @Zephyr don't think for others be so kind